# Dropdown arrow not working on a bootstrap menu item in Rails 6 with Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpacker

```
Rails 6
Webpacker
Mac OS Catalina
```

I started out by adding bootstrap through yarn:

```
yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

Here's what I have in my app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import "bootstrap"
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";
import "../stylesheets/application"

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

const images = require.context('../images', true)
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

And in app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss, I have:

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free";
```

I am trying to implement some dropdown menu items using a bootstrap button. The view code is:

```
.dropdown
  button#AccountsMenu.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"
    = t('nav_bar.accounts')
  = render ('layouts/navbar_partials/accounts')

.dropdown
  button#CustomersMenu.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"
    = t('nav_bar.customers')
  = render ('layouts/navbar_partials/customers')
```

and in app/views/layouts/navbar_partials/customers.html.slim, I have:

```
.dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="CustomersMenu"
  button.dropdown-item type="button"
    = link_to  t('customers.active_customers'), active_customers_customers_path
  button.dropdown-item type="button"
    = link_to t('customers.menu.inactive_customers'), inactive_customers_customers_path
```

When I run the app (from my local development environment), I don't get any error messages.

I can see the bootstrap-styled buttons (see one of them in attached image), but when I click on the arrow, nothing happens, and no activity registers in the local terminal session I am running the rails server from.

[image]

I do not have boostrap in my Gemdfile, but my understanding, is that it's not needed. I added it to see if it makes a difference, but nothing changed.

This might be related to webpacker, but I don't know webpacker enough. Any ideas?

config/webpack/environment.js, has the following in it:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)
module.exports = environment
```

Comment: Did you add the required code to your `environment.js` file?

Comment: See the edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap needs JQuery loaded beforehand so require (not import) it explicitly after JQuery.

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

var jQuery = require("jquery");

global.$ = global.jQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

require("bootstrap");
```